# Change button text according to all values of same tag in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following HTML code

```
<i>0</i>
<i>0</i>
<i>0</i>

<button>Test</button>
```

values inside HTML tag `<i>` are changed individually. What would be the Jquery Code to check if all of `<i>` values are 0 then change button value "Test" to "Test2"

I tried

```
$(document).click(function(){

if($('i').html()=="0")
{
$('button').html("Test2");
}

});
```

My all `<i>` tags values are still 0 but i can't see button text change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each `i` element and check if it's content is `0`, if it is and `c == 3`(this means there are 3 zeros) change the text of `button` element.

```
var c = 0;
$('i').each(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == '0') {
        c++;
        if (c == 3) {
            $('button').text('Test2');
        }
})
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrpLkLva/4/)

Or you can try this simplified code:

```
if ($('i').text() == '000') {
    $('button').text('Text2');
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrpLkLva/6/)

Comment: Not as expected http://jsfiddle.net/hrpLkLva/2/ . Text of button depends on last value of `<i>`

Comment: @user3667167 - I'm confused, what did you expect?

Comment: If all values of <i> are 0 then change button text to Test2

Comment: Actually you should not go throught ALL array of <i>!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not go throught whole array of `<i>` by the performance reason.
You should use `return false;` inside of `.each()` handler to stop the loop when first non `0` value comes.

```
$(document).click(function(){
    var change = true;
    $('i').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() != '0') {        
            change = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (change)
        $('button').text('Test2');
});
```

Comment: Not as expected jsfiddle.net/hrpLkLva/2  Text of button depends on last value of `<i>` but i want to check if any of value is not zero

Comment: You say if any of <i> is 0. You meant all <i> should be 0 to change the button's text? @user3667167

Comment: Explain it one more time here. @user3667167

Answer (score 0):

You only need:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    // preventing the default action of the button:
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function () {
        // caching the collection of <i> elements:
        var iEls = $('i');
        // comparing the number of <i> elements whose text is '0'
        // against the number of <i> elements, returning a Boolean;
        // if the Boolean is true we return 'text2', if false 'text':
        return iEls.filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim() === '0';
        }).length === iEls.length ? 'text2' : 'text';
    });
});
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text(function() {
    var iEls = $('i');
    return iEls.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().trim() === '0';
    }).length === iEls.length ? 'text2' : 'text';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i>0</i>
<i>0</i>
<i>0</i>

<button>Test</button>
```

While the above looks a little more cumbersome it removes the need for global, or otherwise external variables, which need to be kept track of and avoids having to hard-code the number of `<i>` elements into the comparison.

References:

- [`event.preventDefault()` (jQuery implementation)](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).